# java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy10 cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider

Tags: jax-ws

I'm getting this $Proxy10 cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider.  I added jaxws-rt-2.2.7.jar to my project.

Any suggestions?

Here's my code:

```
    URL wsdlLocation = new URL(url);
    QName portName = new QName(namespace,serviceName);
    UsedCarWSX_Service ws = new UsedCarWSX_Service(wsdlLocation,portName);
    UsedCarWSX usedCarWSX = ws.getUsedCarWSX();

    //---------Populate the UserCredentials-------
    UserCredentials uc = new UserCredentials();
    uc.setUserid(username);
    uc.setPassword(password);
    uc.setProducttype("W");
    javax.xml.ws.Holder<UserCredentials> ucHolder=new Holder<UserCredentials>(uc);

    String vin = vin;
    BBValues vinValues = null;
    CurrentVINValues cvv = null;
    cvv = new CurrentVINValues();
    cvv.setBFillDrilldown(true);
    cvv.setBReturnAddDeducts(false);
    cvv.setBReturnMileage(true);
    cvv.setIAverageAddDeductAdj(0);          
    cvv.setICleanAddDeductAdj(0);
    cvv.setIExtraCleanAddDeductAdj(0);
    cvv.setIMileage(0);
    cvv.setIRoughAddDeductAdj(0);
    cvv.setSCountryCode("U");
    cvv.setSFrequencyCode("W");
    cvv.setSVIN(vin);

    // ---------- Call the web service --------------
    CurrentVINValuesResponse cvr = usedCarWSX.getCurrentVINValues(cvv, ucHolder);

    WSBindingProvider bp=(WSBindingProvider)usedCarWSX;
    List hl=bp.getInboundHeaders();
    UserCredentials incomingUC = parseResponseHeader((Header)hl.get(0));
```

Comment: What is the application server?

Comment: Hi Paul, it is tomcat 6